# Couchbase default admin password change

Tags: nosql, couchbase, couchbase-lite

Is there any impact to change default admin password of couchbase cluster? application is live and we require to change the password. Any safe procedure ? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no impact, Couchbase do not use the admin password internally anywhere. We do it every quarter in all environments including prod.

But be cautious  - If you have hard coded the passwordanywhere in your cron scripts 
 or monitoring utilities etc, then make sure you change it there too.

Comment: Thanks Jithin, we have couchbase 4.6. Is it possible to change from Web UI or need to change from Cli only?

Comment: Well, you cannot do it via UI. The only way is to change it is via cli

Comment: @LetsNoSQL https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/cli/cbcli/couchbase-cli-reset-admin-password.html